# I want to print using java through usb without driver in windows platform

Tags: java, c++, c, windows

I want to print using java through usb without driver in windows platform.I read about driver and get some help from this blog `http://blog.peter.skarpetis.com/archives/2005/04/07/getting-a-handle-on-usbprintsys/` but still now it was not clear how to use WDDK and WSDK becasuse this tool dose not provide any ide along with this.I also try jsr80 and libusb but all of this are mainly for linux or need some manual installation actually I want to bypass them using directy **usbprint.sys**,is it possible to access this directly from java?

If someone have some idea about that please share it and also share some using guide about wddk or wsdk and how to use this from java application.

Comment: Wanting to do this is going very much against how Windows and Java expect programs to behave. Why do you believe you need to print without a driver?

Comment: Looks like you need to package up the code on his blog in a way you can call through JNI. You don't need the DDK. And you may want to get yourself a copy of Visual Studio.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill actually i am inspired by pnp(plug and play) devices which is automatically detected and we can use it.I try to achieve this in printer.I also read some information from msdn and usbprint.sys is the class driver which can do so I am interesed to make this possible using java.